# Firefox solution for opening links in Chromium (supporting multiple user accounts)

Tags: chrome, firefox, hyperlink

I need a solution (add-on etc.) for Firefox that allows me to open links in Chromium.

I’m using [multiple user accounts](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/multi-profiles) (not [profiles](https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-and-using-profiles)) in Chromium, so the add-on should allow me to select in which Chromium account I want to open the link.

#### Firefox add-ons I found (but didn’t test):

- [Open In Chrome](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome/) doesn’t seem to offer a way to choose the Chromium user.
- [Open With](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/open-with/) doesn’t seem to work for links (only opened pages).
- [Open With Google Chrome](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/open-with-google-chrome/) doesn’t advertise supporting Chromium users (has no screenshots/documentation).
- [Open in Chrome™](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome-1/) doesn’t seem to offer a way to choose the Chromium user.